# Do migration votes in minority end up as a flag for the moderators?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons, migration

I reviewed a close vote for [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/124255/17592). There were already four votes: one for migration to Super User (which is available through Closing > Off Topic > Migration), and three for putting on hold as "unclear what you're asking". I voted for migration to Super User as well, which had the result that the question was put on hold as "unclear what you're asking".

That seems strange to me. Is anything done with the migration votes after this closing? Do the moderators see something of this, so that they can decide whether the question should be migrated or not?

For users with less reputation, who cannot vote to close, there's an option to flag a question for migration, and the flag ends up with the moderators, isn't it? So I would expect that the migration votes also end up with the moderators. But it's not clear to me if this actually happens. Does it? And if not, what is the logic behind that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the general case the close reason is chosen by a simple majority so if two users vote for "too broad" and the other three vote for "unclear" the question will be marked as "unclear".

For migrations a super majority of four votes for the target site are required. This is to help prevent poor quality questions being migrated.

So in your case with three "unclear" votes the question will be closed as unclear rather than being migrated.

Re your point about close flag - these don't end up with the moderators. They simply feed the question into the close review queue. Moderators should only be involved if you want to migrate a **high quality** question to a site not on the migration list.